# url into UITextField

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uitextfield

I have a `UIWebView` and `UITextField` in my view but am facing a problem.

The problem is how do I replace the URL of the web page in `UITextField` automatically, as I surf through different web pages?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following property of the *UIWebView* instance:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSURLRequest *request
```

So you can get the current *NSURLRequest* associated with the web view by:

```
NSURLRequest* urlRequest = myWebView.request;
```

You can then get the associated instance of *NSURL* using the following instance method:

```
- (NSURL *)URL
```

So you can now get the *NSURL* object form the UIWebView with the following code:

```
NSURL* url = [myWebView.request URL];
```

To convert this to a string you can use either the `absoluteString` or `relativeString` instance methods of *NSURL*. For this example I'll use absoluteString.

```
NSString* urlString = [[myWebView.request URL] absoluteString];
```

Now we can set the the text of the *UITextField* using the simple text property:

```
myTextField.text = [[myWebView.request URL] absoluteString];
```

So now all we need to do is ensure that the previous line of code gets called at the correct time in order to update the text field with the url text whenever the page changes. To do this, we need to use a class which is a delegate of the *UIWebView* (and thus conforms to the *UIWebViewDelegate* protocol). If you're unsure about how to use delegates I strongly suggest you do some reading of the delegate design patterns and Apple Developer documentation, as it's used throughout iOS development.

In your *UIWebViewDelegate* class, you need to implement the following method as follows:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    myTextField.text = [[myWebView.request URL] absoluteString];
}
```

This will ensure the text field always displays the url of the page that last started to load (there are other *UIWebViewDelegate* methods if you'd rather the text field be updated at a different time).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In .H file u declare webview, textfield and IbAction to browse the text u enter and it looks like

```
  {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *web;

IBOutlet UITextField *text;
  }
 -(IBAction)search:(id)sender;
```

and .M file looks in IBaction

```
 -(IBAction)search:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"%@",text.text);

NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",text.text];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[web loadRequest:requestObj];
   }
```

surely this works

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` in the webview delegate.

This method will call for every request load in the web view.

In this you can get the request Object. From that you can get the URL.

You can directly paste the URL in the textField in this method.

Answer (score 0):

You should define – webViewDidStartLoad: method of id delegate of your UIWebView:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
      yourUITextField.text = [[webView.request URL] path];
}
```

[All from documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate)